# AngularJS templateUrl not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

Hello and thanks in advance.  I am working on getting my views to show on my index.html page.  I can see in the http requests when clicking on my links that the appropriate template is being retrieved but it just is not being displayed.  It's like it's having trouble associating my template html with the ng-view tag.  My templates also have only one root element and all else seems to be working as it should.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Also if I just use template instead of templateUrl and add the html that way it works as well.

```
var app = angular.module('fireground', [ 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize' ])

        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                    .when('/', {
                        templateUrl : 'pages/test.html',
                        controller  : 'RootCtrl'
                    })
                    .when('/one', {
                        templateUrl : 'pages/test2.html',
                        controller  : 'RootCtrl'

                    })
                    .when('/newsletter', {
                        controller  : 'RootCtrl',
                        templateUrl : 'pages/test3.html'
                    });

                    //.otherwise({
                    //  redirectTo: '/one'
                    //});
        }])
.controller('RootCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.messages = "Test Test Test Test Test Test";
})
```

And my Index.html(slimmed down)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>TheFireStore App</title> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0,     maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular-route.min.js">          </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angular/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angular/factories.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angular/directives.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angular/services.js"></script>


</head>     
<body data-ng-app="fireground"> 

<div id="slidemenu">

    <ul id="slideUL">

        <li><img class="doubleLine" src="./images/doublelines.jpg" /></li>
        <li><a onclick="$(document).unbind('touchmove');" class="navlnk Left" href="#one" data-transition="slide">FIREGROUND LIVE <span class="floatR">&raquo;</span></a></li>
        <li><img class="doubleLine" src="./images/doublelines.jpg" /></li>
        <li><a href="">DEALS</a>
            <ul style="margin:-15px 0 0 40px;">
              <li><a onclick="$(document).unbind('touchmove');" class="navlnk Center" href="#products" data-transition="slide">Apparel</a></li>
              <li><a onclick="$(document).unbind('touchmove');" class="navlnk Center" href="#products" data-transition="slide">PPE</a></li>
              <li><a onclick="$(document).unbind('touchmove');" class="navlnk Center" href="#products" data-transition="slide">Helmets</a></li>
              <li><a onclick="$(document).unbind('touchmove');" class="navlnk Center" href="#products" data-transition="slide">Boots</a></li>
              <li><a onclick="$(document).unbind('touchmove');" class="navlnk Center" href="#products" data-transition="slide">Flashlights</a></li>
              <li><a onclick="$(document).unbind('touchmove');" class="navlnk Center" href="#products" data-transition="slide">Tools</a></li>
              <li><a onclick="$(document).unbind('touchmove');" class="navlnk Center" href="#products" data-transition="slide">Bags &amp; Packs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><img class="doubleLine" src="./images/doublelines.jpg" /></li>
        <li><a onclick="$(document).unbind('touchmove');" class="navlnk Right" href="#newsletter" data-transition="slide">NEWSLETTER<span class="floatR">&raquo;</span></a></li>
        <li><img class="doubleLine" src="./images/doublelines.jpg" /></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.thefirestore.com/mobile" rel="external">Shop TheFireStore.com <span class="floatR">&raquo;</span></a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

 <div id="master">

 <div class="header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#" class="navlinkstyle" data-slidemenu="#slidemenu" data-slideopen="true" data-corners="false" data-iconpos="notext"><img border="0" src="./images/imageMenu.jpg" /></a>
    <img height="62" style="width:100%" class="imgCenter" src="./images/firegroundLogo.jpg" />
</div>
</div>

    <div ng-view></div>


</body>
</html>
```

And my simple html template is:

```
<h1 style="color:black">The message is:  {{messages}}</h1>
```

Comment: Where is your ngview tag

Comment: Have you checked that the response to the AJAX request loading the template is successful, and contains the appropriate HTML code? Is there a RootCtrl controller defined in your application? Is it loaded by the index.html page? Try creating a plnkr reproducing the problem.

Comment: ng-view tag is present on the index.html page.  And the RootCtrl is also there with a very simple static scope message to be displayed.

Comment: And the AJAX request does include the appropriate html code but it never seems to be included on the index.html page.  Working now on a JSFiddle example.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of your `index.html`

Comment: I edited my original post to include my index.html.

Comment: Here is a plunk with most of your code. Seems to be working fine. http://embed.plnkr.co/or41jnR14FY9CaunI25A/